# Using MVC model, cant get values from output into jinja2 template (python)

Tags: python-3.x, flask, jinja2

Not sure why my variable is empty when i load the flask app...

viewmodel:

```
from flask import current_app

from app.viewmodels.shared.viewmodelbase import ViewModelBase
from app.infrastructure import redact_name

import canarytools, requests, json, urllib3
from os import path
from prettytable import PrettyTable
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter, Retry


class Canaries(ViewModelBase):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = "Canaries"
        self.auth = "password"
        self.console = canarytools.Console('user', 'password')
        self.baseurl = "https://user.canary.tools/api/v1/devices/live"
        self.payload = {
            'auth_token': 'password'
        }
        self.flash_error()

        self.get_live_birds()
        self.get_dead_birds()
        self.unackalerts()

    def get_live_birds(self):

        livebirds_table = PrettyTable()
        livebirds_table.field_names = ["Name", "Location", "IP", "Uptime"]
        for device in self.console.devices.live():
            livebirds_table.add_row([device.name, device.location, device.ip_address, device.uptime_age])
        livebirds_table.sortby = "Name"
        html = livebirds_table.get_html_string()
        return html

    def get_dead_birds(self):
        deadbirds_table = PrettyTable()
        deadbirds_table.field_names = ["Name", "Location", "Personality", "Downtime"]
        for device in self.console.devices.dead():
            deadbirds_table.add_row([device.name, device.location, device.ippers, device.uptime_age])
        deadbirds_table.sortby = "Name"
        return deadbirds_table

    def unackalerts(self):
        unackalertnum = len(self.console.incidents.unacknowledged())
        unackalerts_table = PrettyTable()
        unackalerts_table.field_names = ["Type", "Attacker"]
        for alert in self.console.incidents.unacknowledged():
            alertcount = 0
            unackalerts_table.add_row([alert.summary, alert.src_host])
            if alertcount == unackalertnum:
                exit(0) 
        return unackalertnum
```

jinja2 html page:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block app_content %}
    <div class="container">
        <table class="table table-hover table-striped w-auto" style="margin: auto">
            <tbody>

            <tr>
                <td>{{ html | safe}}</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

view:

```
from flask import render_template, session, g, current_app
from flask_login import current_user
import datetime

from app.bin.utils import log_request
from app.bin.auth_functions import login_required_with_ip_whitelist

from app.viewmodels.canaries.canaries_viewmodel import Canaries

from app.views.canaries import bp


@bp.before_request
def before_request():
    session.permanent = True
    current_app.permanent_session_lifetime = datetime.timedelta(hours=8)
    session.modified = True
    g.user = current_user


@bp.route("/canary/live_birds", methods=["GET"])
@login_required_with_ip_whitelist
def live_birds():
    log_request()
    vm = Canaries()
    return render_template("canaries/live-birds.html", **vm.to_dict())


@bp.route("/canary/dead_birds", methods=["GET"])
@login_required_with_ip_whitelist
def dead_birds():
    log_request()
    vm = Canaries()
    return render_template("canaries/dead-birds.html", **vm.to_dict())
```

My Api variable html prints fine to the terminal when i do print (api for canaries), but when i call it from Jinja2 it is empty i can convert it to html but it still doesnt work when i use it in my jinja2 template,

im stuck and the guy that developed out backend platform based on the MVC model left the company!

viewmodelbase class:

```
class ViewModelBase:
    def __init__(self, default_limit: int = 10):
        self.request: Request = flask.request
        self.request_dict: dict = request_dict.create("")

        self.title: Optional[str] = "Security Ops"
        self.error: Optional[str] = None
        self.hide_nav: bool = hide_nav.get_hide_nav(self.request)
        self.table_sm: bool = table_sm.get_table_sm(self.request)
        self.hide_buttons: bool = hide_nav.get_hide_button(self.request)
        self.hide_header: bool = False
        self.redactable: bool = False
        self.limitable: bool = False
        self.limit: Optional[int] = utils.try_int(
            self.request_dict.get("limit", default_limit)
        )
        self.dark_mode: bool = dark_mode.get_dark_mode_cookie(self.request)

    def to_dict(self):
        return self.__dict__

    def flash_error(self):
        if self.error:
            flask.flash(self.error)
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the `to_dict` method does not produce a `dict` with a key `html` in it.

Also some things seem odd :

- calling `get_live_birds` and `get_dead_birds` inside the VM init instead of when you need it (ie. in the `view`)
- not assigning the results of those calls to variables
- `get_live_birds` produces an html, whereas `get_dead_birds` returns the instance of `PrettyTable`

**UPDATE :**
In the ViewModel class, remove calls to methods get_live_birds, get_dead_birds, unackalerts from the `__init__`. Since their results are not assign to `self.xxx` running them on `__init__` is not useful.

Then you can update your view like so:

```python
@bp.route("/canary/live_birds", methods=["GET"])
@login_required_with_ip_whitelist
def live_birds():
    log_request()
    vm = Canaries()
    live_birds_html = vm.get_live_birds()
    return render_template("canaries/live-birds.html",{"html": live_birds_html})
```

Comment: i uploaded the viewmodelbase class

Comment: i was just testing the html output, i dont care how its really formated it just comes in as empty in jinja2

Comment: not assigning the results of those calls to variables, how do i do this? i thought i could just put the variable inside the jinja2 template